# Server and Client Interactions

Tags: java

Hello programmers on the internet. I am currently stepping through an operating systems book and there are some exercises that involve the following pieces of code.

This is the server code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DateServer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
              ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(6013);
              // now listen for connections
              while (true) {
           Socket client = sock.accept();
           PrintWriter pout = new
           PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
           // write the Date to the socket
           pout.println(new java.util.Date().toString());
           // close the socket and resume
           // listening for connections
           client.close();
           }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
           System.err.println(ioe);
        }
   }
}
```

This is the client code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DateClient{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
              //make connection to server socket
              Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",6013);
              InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader bin = new
              BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              // read the date from the socket
              String line;
              while ( (line = bin.readLine()) != null)
                     System.out.println(line);
              // close the socket connection
               sock.close();
             }
         catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
         }
    }
 }
```

So to my understanding the server is creating a socket and writing a date value to it. The client is then coming a long and connecting to the server and writing out the value in that socket. Am I interpreting this code correctly? This is my first experience with sockets.

Now for my actual question. I want to have the client connect to the server (and print out a message saying you are connected) and then be able to send a value over to the server so that the server can process it. How would I go about doing this? I have tried tinkering with DataOutputStream and DataInputStream but I have never used either before. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: So many examples on this site. Look especially to the barrage of recent questions about chat clients.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You have the server writing to the socket and the client reading from the socket. You want to reverse that.

Server Should look like:

```
ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(6013);
// now listen for connections
while (true)
{
    Socket client = sock.accept();

    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    // read the date from the client socket
    String line;
    while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    // close the socket connection
    client.close();
}
```

The client should look like:

```
try
{
    // make connection to server socket
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6013);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);

    // send a date to the server
    out.println("1985");
    sock.close();
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    System.err.println(ioe);
}
```

Comment: Okay that is reassuring that I was understanding that correctly and thank you! It looks like when I run the server and then the client nothing is printing out to stdout. I will debug and see if I can figure out why that is.

Comment: hmmm I am not sure why but it seems like the code is never hitting the while statement. When I run the client it executes and closes the socket without any print statements.

Comment: With the code I have in the example, it should just be the server that prints to the console.

Comment: Sorry I worded that incorrectly. Yeah I am getting nothing in my console. I am also noticing some weird behavior with my eclipse though. Does it show up on your console?

Comment: Wait here we go. It looks like my Eclipse was bugging out for a bit and just wasn't sending anything to the console. It is showing up now. Thank you so much for your help! :)